# Smart Device projects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-phone-7

Has anyone tried to install the new Windows Phone 7 tools?  Mainly, I would like to know if it allows Visual Studio 2010 to open Smart Device projects from older versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smart device projects from earlier versions (e.g. WIndows Mobile 6.X) are not supported in Visual Studio 2010.

There are no plans to add this support to VS2010. You'll have to keep using VS2008 for such projects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx states that:

> Visual Studio 2010 does not support
>   mobile application development for
>   versions of Windows Phone prior to
>   Windows Phone OS 7.0.
>
> For Visual Studio 2008 mobile
>   developers, Microsoft released the
>   Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit,
>   which works with the Windows Mobile 6
>   SDK.
>
> Because Visual Studio 2010 does not
>   support mobile application development
>   for Windows Phone prior to Windows
>   Phone OS 7.0, you cannot use the
>   following features: .NET Compact
>   Framework projects, Visual C++ device
>   projects, smart device CAB projects,
>   Device Emulator and Device Emulator
>   Manager, testing tools for device
>   projects, and Device Security Manager.
>
> Mobile application development is
>   still supported in earlier versions of
>   Visual Studio, such as Visual Studio
>   2008. For more information about smart device projects, see Windows Mobile
>   Developer Center and Smart Device
>   Development in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I thought the idea was that once the Windows Phone 7 tools came out, they would be supported.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @Bryan - If they did add the support it would essentially be duplication of work that has already been done in VS2008. (Remember VS2010 was a massive rewrite and so it wouldn't be a straight port.) I think that effort is best spent in adding new functionality to Visual Studio, WP7 & Windows Embedded Handheld, rather than duplicating effort.

Comment: That makes sense. I just thought I read something about adding support around the time when VS2010 first shipped. Maybe it was wishful thinking but the author(s) of the article(s) I read.

Comment: Link from Chris Tacke's blog: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: I still feel extremely strongly that support for non WinPhone builds needs to be added to VS2010.  Not everyone writing device apps today is targeting Phone, and having to mix old and new tools for a solution flat-out sucks.  Now whether or not that will ever actually happen I have no idea.  From the MS perspective I'm sure it's all about ROI, and they just don't feel that there's a lot of return for the non-phone stuff (though I'd love to argue the case with the decision maker that thinks this).  I've even requested that they open source it so we can add it ourselves, but heard nothing back.

Comment: @ctacke it would be nice but I'm not holding my breath waiting

Comment: Oh, I'm not holding my breath either - not on any of my desires.  The next version of Platform Builder still uses VS2008, so until that moves to a newer version of Studio (they'll probably target VS2010 whenever VSvNext is outwith the way they operate) we're probably stuck.  The frusatrating bit is that they obviously have all of the requisite Compact Framework build and debug infrastructure in place since you can build apps for WinPhone, they just are choosing to not let non-Phone devs use it.  I need to stop thinking about it because all it accomplishes is to raise my blood pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Latest posting on the [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010) site indicates there may be some kind of support coming Q1 2013, with more details available in September on www.windowsembedded.com

```
Posted by Microsoft on 13/06/2012 at 10:55 

Hi folks,

In the first quarter of 2013, we plan to provide tooling for Visual Studio 2012 to 
create apps for Windows Embedded Compact v.Next. We’ll be announcing more details 
in September, including the roadmap for .NET CF. You can find more details this 
Fall in the Windows Embedded Compact website at http://www.windowsembedded.com. 

thanks,
Doug Turnure
Visual Studio PM
```